# How do I safely remotely connect to my database via SSH?

Tags: ssh, mysql, mysql-workbench, navicat

I have these users in **MySQL** database

```
mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;                                                             
+------------------+-----------+                                                                     
| User             | Host      |                                                                     
+------------------+-----------+                                                                     
| root             | 127.0.0.1 |                                                                     
| root             | ::1       |                                                                                                                                         
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |                                                                     
| root             | localhost |                                                                     
+------------------+-----------+                                                                     
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)                                                                             
                                                                                                     
mysql>
```

---

I have a user `kyo` in my VM.

*Is the user in the he VM is different than the user in MySQL ?*

Do I need to create another `kyo` user in MySQL ?

What do I need to be able to connect to my MySQL remotely from my local machine ?

---

I added a user

```
select User,Host from mysql.user;
CREATE USER 'kyo'@'24.62.137.111' IDENTIFIED BY 'p4$$w0rd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'kyo'@'24.62.137.111';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
select User,Host from mysql.user;
```

I see this now

```
mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+------------------+---------------+
| User             | Host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1     |
| kyo              | 24.62.137.111 |
| root             | ::1           |
| root             | iggy          |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| root             | localhost     |
+------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I kept getting

> 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"

---

## Update

I ran nmap scan

I see this

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE                                                                            
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

Is that mean my port 3306 is not open to the public ? and I should for remote access ? correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Navicat seems to have option to create SSH tunnel for MySQL connection.

When you create a new connection

[image: NaviCAT General Tab]

Whatever connection you had there - you can use the Root Username/Password. If you want to create a separate username / password for MySQL - you can do that too. The Host is localhost (because you are connecting locally).

[image: NaviCAT SSH Tab]

In the SSH tab - you enter your SSH credentials (how you SSH into the VM).

And to answer your questions:

- Is the user in the he VM is different than the user in MySQL ? *Yes. user kyo on the VM is a separate user to kyo in the MySQL - and it can have different password as well.*
- Do I need to create another kyo user in MySQL ? *If you prefer*
- What do I need to be able to connect to my MySQL remotely from my local machine ? *As above - SSH tunnel to your MySQL instance.*

---

(Note: Personal opinion)
Unless absolutely necessary - I wouldn't make the MySQL instance public. Leave it behind the VM and access it locally (over SSH tunnel).

---

EDIT (to provide clarification):

- MySQL server is already "open" on port 3306 but as per your mysql db - it will only accept connection from some accounts (root@localhost, and kyo@24.62.137.111).
- The VM itself has its own set of rules (for allowing incoming connection). You need to open Port 3306 on the VM.
- You need to change the "kyo" username to allow localhost connection (not that IP) since you are not connecting directly from your machine (24.62.137.111) to the MySQL server. You are connecting to the SSH server on your VM - and then connecting over localhost to the MySQL server. Edit the kyo on mysql to be kyo@localhost - and the ssh tunneling will work.

Comment: @kyo - Then open the port.  The host would be `24.62.137.111` if your wondering or localhost if it's the same machine.

Comment: @kyo - Your question doesn’t ask how to do that.  This answer as it’s currently written answers the question that was asked